# Can GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB be enabled selectively for parts of an app versus the whole thing?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

App Engine docs say you can enable sockets for http by using:

```
env_variables:
     GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB : 'anyvalue'
```

So imagine you want to use sockets for an https request in file1.py, but in file2.py you don't need sockets and in fact you're calling a non-whitelisted IP address so can't use them, is there a way to turn them off for file2.py so the http lib uses the standard method?

Or you can of course go about this from the other direction, can you selectively turn it on for file1.py versus the entire app?

Thanks!

Comment: As a possible workaround for those of you who find yourself in this predicament I tried using the urlfetch library directly from the app engine stack assuming it wasn't setup use sockets anyhow and found this to be a viable solution, so while I have't tested it throughly it seems to work so far. I will report back if it breaks down.